# Adding a `-` to a string once at 8 chars, then again at 4?

Tags: c#, guid

I've been trying to do this for the past hour and it's driving me insane.
I am trying to get a minecraft UUID with proper formatting (with the dashes), but the API I use gives it in a regular format.

> What I have: `7a4730f8f948471dbc77f6f71a250f87`
>
> Proper format: `7a4730f8-f948-471d-bc77-f6f71a250f87`

How would I go about formatting the string like this?

Comment: How do you format the uuid? What is your current approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The .NET framework has a [**`Guid`** class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx). You can invoke the constructor and use `.ToString()` to get the above described format. For instance:

```
csharp> new Guid("7a4730f8f948471dbc77f6f71a250f87")
7a4730f8-f948-471d-bc77-f6f71a250f87
csharp> new Guid("7a4730f8f948471dbc77f6f71a250f87").ToString()
"7a4730f8-f948-471d-bc77-f6f71a250f87"
```

In case you process the UUIDs internally, I advice you to use the `GUID` class instead of a string: since now you can easily compare two GUIDs, etc.

Furthermore I expect that there are less bugs in the .NET framework than in code created by users (not because they are less competent, but because the number of users of the .NET framework is large, bugs are easily spotted and solved).